# Meaning of curly "f" in console log for JS object?

Tags: javascript, object, console, console.log

I'm new to console logging and I got an object to be displayed but I don't understand the meaning of `f (file_attachment)`.

See

[image: screenshot of console log of object]

How can I grab the `file_attachment`, if it's even possible? I need to get the file.

UPDATE: Here's a better look at the object.

[image: screenshot 2]

Comment: It stands for `function`.

Comment: There is no file attachment, that's just the name of the function's parameter.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in the function, and then when the breakpoint is hit you can access the `file_attachment` variable.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you. But is the function called success and I call it by object.success(file_attachment)?

Comment: The name of the function is `success`. I don't know what property it's in, the screenshot is cut off at the line that shows the name of the variable.

Comment: @Barmar I just added a better screenshot. Thank you for your help thus far.

Comment: It's whatever is the argument to `console.log()`